# How to pause/resume a JQueryUI Effect

Tags: jquery-ui

I have an effect which I run:

```
$(this).effect("highlight", { color: "#669966" }, 5000, revert);
```

I would like that this effect is paused and resumed within my hover event below, but cannot seem to accomplish this:

```
$(this).parent().hover(
    function() {
        if($('.submenu', this).length > 0) {
            $('.submenu', this).css('display', 'inline-block');
        }
        //pause timer

    },
    function() {
        if($('.submenu', this).length > 0) {
            $('.submenu', this).css('display', 'none');
        }
        //resume timer    

    }
);
```

Could someone please show me how to pause this JQueryUI event.

Thanks Devin

Comment: Try this plugin: http://tobia.github.com/Pause/ not sure if it works for effects but it works great for animations.

Comment: Thanks, that is useful for animations, however doesn't seem to apply to effects. Anyone else got any thoughts or advice on this?